# Why should Request header be set after the connection is opened in AJAX?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have been reading this code online:

```
function ajax_post(){

    var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    var url = "my_parse_file.php";
    var fn = document.getElementById("first_name").value;
    var ln = document.getElementById("last_name").value;
    var vars = "firstname="+fn+"&lastname="+ln;

    hr.open("POST", url, true); // line 1

    hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); // line 2

    hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
            var return_data = hr.responseText;
            document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = return_data;
        }
    }

    hr.send(vars); 
    document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "processing...";
}
```

And I fail to understand why we should set the request header  **AFTER** opening the connection 
According to my logic you first craft the packet header, content everything and the send the data , but why are we doing it the reverse way in the above example.

Comment: The header isn't set after the request is being made. `hr.send();` is where the call/request is being made, the rest are call properties and event listeners.

Comment: Sorry I meant after the connection is opened .~

Comment: The connection is opened on send, open is what it will open, you could say its a function based property setter. `The XMLHttpRequest.open() method initializes a request.`